# Spring boot Autowired em JFrame

Tags: java, swing, injeção-de-dependência, spring-boot, ioc

No desenvolvimento de uma aplicação Spring Boot para Desktop, é possível injetar um `@Repository` em uma classe `JFrame`?

Se sim como? Alguma alternativa?

Exemplos de código:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {}

public class ItemFrame extends JFrame {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository repository;

}
```

Esse código dá `NullPointerException`, já tentei anotar a classe com `@Component` e `@Controller` mas em sucesso.

---

Segue exemplo da classe principal.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
        new ItemFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Para o autowired funcionar a classe tem que ser instanciada pelo Spring. Onde a classe ItemFrame está sendo instanciada no seu código?

Comment: Estou instanciando manualmente na classe principal, conforme editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O Spring não vai gerenciar instâncias criadas com new! O próprio Spring deve criar a instância da classe para que as injeções funcionem. O certo seria injetar o objeto itemFrame pelo Spring também, mas como o método main é static não podemos injetar com @Autowired. Uma alternativa é obter a instância criada pelo Spring por meio do ApplicationContext como a seguir:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class)
    .headless(false).run(args);
    ItemFrame a = context.getBean(ItemFrame.class);
    a.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Quando você anota uma classe com @Component, @Service , @Repository ou @Controller o Spring cria uma instância dessa classe chamando o seu construtor sem parâmetros ou o construtor anotado com @Autowired se existir. Ao criá-la, ele injeta todas as suas dependências corretamente e a instância fica em seu ApplicationContext. Classes criadas com new não serão gerenciadas pelo Spring, a não ser que você as coloque no contexto de aplicação manualmente.

Além disso, para rodar com Spring Boot você deve colocar a opção .headless(false). E também a classe ItemFrame deve ser anotada com @Component para poder ser injetada.

```
@Component
public class ItemFrame extends JFrame{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Vou testar ao chegar em casa, então posto aqui o resultado.

Comment: Após testar. Tal código (usando `ItemFrame` como `static` para a chamada) não funciona. Gera um NullPointer Exception.

Comment: De onde vem essa `DemoApplication.class`? Seria o nome da classe principal da minha própria aplicação? Precisa anotar a(s) classe(s) do JFrame?

Comment: Testei mas sem sucesso ainda. Ele cria o frame, mas não injeta itens com `@Autowired` dentro dele.

Comment: Além do seu eu adicionei `.web(false)` na frente de `.headless(false)`. A exceção que ocorre é NullPointerException na linha que chamo algum método de `repository`. A janela é injetada e aberta corretamente seu eu não colocar `repository` dentro dela.

Comment: Coloquei a anotação `@Compoment` em `ItemFrame`. `ItemRepository` é uma interface. A "mágica" que eu quero do Spring é justamente por extender de `CrudRepository`. No ambiente web ele me traz um repositório completo automaticamente, quero isso no desktop.

Comment: Bom, você pode injetar um Repository em qualquer classe, incluindo uma que estende JFrame. Desculpe, achei que a pergunta era essa! Quando vi Repository pensei em uma interface sendo implementada por uma classe qualquer, mas realmente pelo exemplo o ItemRepository está usando Spring Data, faz sentido. O que você quer então é como usar Spring Data em um app de desktop é isso?

Comment: A ideia é também essa mesmo. Spring Data JPA funciona muito bem em Web, mas não consigo usar em desktop. Também seria injetar outras classes como um service/utilitário se precisar nos JFrames. Muita gente usa Spring, mas não para desktop (parece).